# Removing a 'range' of characters at specific indexes in string

Tags: python, string, list

I have looked over similar questions, but I still have trouble figuring this one out.

I have two Lists of strings, one of which consists of characters like 'abcdefg' and another one consisting of strings which consist of white spaces and a special character. The special character indicates where I should remove characters from my 'abcdefg' string. The special character's position in the list would be the same position I would need to remove a character from the first list. I also need to remove the adjacent characters.

EDIT: I want to remove a character (and the adjacent characters) at the same position the '*' char is located in airstrikes, but in reinforces. Does this make sense?

```
reinforces = ["abcdefg", "hijklmn"]
airstrikes = ["   *   "]
battlefield = reinforces[0]
bomb_range = []
count = 0

if range(len(airstrikes)) != 0:
    for airstrike in airstrikes:
        for char in airstrike:
            print(count)
            count = count + 1
            if (char == '*'):
                bomb_range.append(count-1)
                bomb_range.append(count)
                bomb_range.append(count+1)
                break


#Trying to hardcode it initially just to get it to work. Some kind of looping is needed though.
battlefield = battlefield[:bomb_range[0]] + battlefield[bomb_range[1]:]
battlefield = battlefield[:bomb_range[1]] + battlefield[bomb_range[2]:]
#battlefield = battlefield[:bomb_range[2]] + battlefield[bomb_range[3]:] #Will not work of course. But how could I achieve what I want?
```

I am sorry about the nested loops. If it hurts looking at it, feel free to bash and correct me. I am sorry if I missed any answers on this forum which could have helped me find a solution. Know that I did try to find one.

Comment: I see no question in your full text. What do you want to know?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want to do. How, exactly, does the content in `airstrikes` tell you how to transform `reinforces`? Show examples of the results you would expect if your transform was successful; given the examples here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Since you haven't specified a problem, we're at a loss.

Comment: I have updated the description. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Use `index` to find where to strike, then remove the character the usual way:

```
>>> reinforce = "abcdefg"
>>> airstrike = "   *   "
>>> strike_at = airstrike.index('*')
>>> reinforce[:strike_at]+reinforce[strike_at+1:]
'abcefg'
```

of course, you need to make sure `strike_at+1` is a legal index (see `try` and `except`).

Comment: I thought I needed to do some kind of error handling to check if it was out of bounds. Index seems like a smart solution. I will try it out

Comment: @DonutSteve You do. That is why I suggested googling/searching `try/except`. You could compare to `len(airstrike)`, but that is less idiomatic in Python.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was just stating I had thought about it. So it is nice to see I was on the right track